# LibGDX: Display Sprite only inside certain area

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

I program some sort of board game. Objects are supposed to be able to slide off that board. That means that the part the object that is outside that speicified area should not be shown anymore to make it look as if the item is moving off the board.

What I've tried is to check whether the sprite is still on the board or not (by checking the position) and if it wasn't, I'd not render it anymore. But that is

1) bad because then the Sprite is either shown completely or not at all.

2) unelegant.

What is an elegant method to achieve what I've described above? Maybe use images instead of sprites and then have another stage with a viewport that is only part of the screen? If so, I'd be happy about some explanation on how to do that.

Comment: What about always rendering all objects completely and in the end render a border/frame/background around your board. Thus covering parts of the objects in the end, which are outside of the board?

Comment: I suppose it would wir, but it's not very elegant, is it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Clipping. What it basically does is that you define a rectangle area an associate it to a spritebatch. you apply the scissors and only the area inside of the rectangle that is assosiated to the spritebatch will be drawn.

Example code from Wiki (**before version 0.9.9**):

```
Rectangle scissors = new Rectangle();
Rectangle clipBounds = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
ScissorStack.calculateScissors(camera, spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix(), clipBounds, scissors);
ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);
spriteBatch.draw(...);
spriteBatch.flush();
ScissorStack.popScissors();
```

Source: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping%2C-with-the-use-of-scissorstack

--

**EDIT:**
For LibGDX version 0.9.9, the parameters for the function calculateScissors seemed to change. NathanSweet helped me out figuring out how to make it work ([CalculateScissors with ViewPorts](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/807)) and then the function mentioned above was reintroduced ([CalculateScissors Less Parameters](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/ec0abea1f7287e8748afb6f1ecf458ab952d5f17)).

```
ScissorStack.calculateScissors(camera, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), batch.getTransformMatrix(), clipBounds, scissor);
```